# Aligning/Spacing multiple variables in select option

Tags: html, css, forms, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have a select where for each option I list the person's name and their role, as an example:

```
John Smith            Teacher
Ronald MacDonald    Doctor
Jane Hope            Secretary
John Smith            Chef
```

As you can see there is an ample space between the person's name and their role to make it easier to the user that they are selecting the correct person.

However is there a way that I can get the roles to all align with each other? I tried using Len(personName) to get the number of characters in a person's name and take that off a total number of spaces but the issue here is obviously the letter 'i' and 'm' still count as one character although they are different widths so it is still out of alignment.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: _“but the issue here is obviously the letter 'i' and 'm' still count as one character although they are different widths”_ – well use a monospace font for the options then …

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dropdown list with 2 columns like so:

```css
#dropdown-menu {
    list-style:none;
}
#dropdown-menu ul.left-side {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline=-block;
}
#dropdown-menu ul.right-side {
    float:left;
    width:70px;
    list-style:none;
    vertical-align:top;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="dropdown-menu">
    <ul class="left-side">
        <li>Ronald MacDonald</li>
        <li>John Smith</li>
        <li>Ronnie Corbett</li>
        <li>Jane Austen</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="right-side">
        <li>Teacher</li>
        <li>Doctor</li>
        <li>Comedian</li>
        <li>Chef</li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there are no ways to align `option` content without serious workarounds. If you want to keep original HTML `select` you can try this approach (it uses monospace font).

Yes, object's fields are hardcoded. Shame on me.

```js
$(function () {
    var crew = [
        { name: "John Doe", rank: "Captain" },
        { name: "Just Someguy", rank: "Seaman" },
        { name: "And Someone", rank: "Seaman" }
    ];
    
    var getLongestFirstColumnValue = function(data) {
        var maxLength = data[0].name.length;
        for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
            if (data[i].name.length > maxLength) {
                maxLength = data[i].name.length;
            }
        }
        return maxLength;
    }
    
    var placeholderSize = getLongestFirstColumnValue(crew) + 5;
    
    var convertPlaceholderToSpaces = function(count) {
        var spaces = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            spaces += "&nbsp;";
        }
        return spaces;
    }
    
    var buildOption = function(person, firstColumnPlaceholder) {
        var formattedContent = person.name + convertPlaceholderToSpaces((firstColumnPlaceholder - person.name.length)) + person.rank + "&nbsp;&nbsp;";
        return "<option value=\"" + person.name + "\">" + formattedContent  + "</option>";
    };
    
    for (var i = 0; i < crew.length; i++) {
        $("#test-select").append(buildOption(crew[i], placeholderSize));
    }
});
```

```css
#test-select {
    font-family: "Courier New";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="test-select">
</select>
```